# Openshift Job Trigger

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

We have batch job that process flat files which gets triggered using Rest Call

```
For e.g. https://clustername.com/loader?filname=file1.dat
    https://clustername.com/loader?filname=file2.dat
    https://clustername.com/loader?filname=file3.dat
```

We want to configure Openshift Job to trigger this batch job.

```
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/jobs.html
```

As per the Kubernetes documentation, the job can be triggered using Queue:

```
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/
```

Can the job also be triggered by Rest Call?

Comment: It should be doable, it would be an API call to the controller...probably just a job definition YAML, the equivalent of an `oc run` but using the API.

Comment: Generally everything in Openshift and Kubernetes is created using Rest calls. For example, in Kubernetes you can run "kubectl -v 10 create -f manifest.yaml" and it will give you appropriate curl commands. So you can easily create jobs using Rest API.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you can instantiate a job by creating a new one via the API.

IIRC you'll make a POST call to `/apis/batch/v1/namespaces/<your-namespace>/jobs`
(The endpoint may be slightly different depending on your API versions.)

The payload for your REST call is the JSON formatted manifest for the job you want to run. i.e.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "batch/v1",
    "kind": "Job",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "example"
    },
    "spec": {
        "selector": {},
        "template": {
            "metadata": {
                "name": "example"
            },
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "name": "example",
                        "image": "hello-world"
                    }
                ],
                "restartPolicy": "Never"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to Include DeploymentConfig, Job ,Service and Route.. Do we have a configuration where i can include Job as part of DeploymentConfig .                                           Job --> DeploymentConfig--> Service --> Route

Comment: Those are separate resources so you'd need to create them individually with their own API calls.